# move_uploaded_file returns true but file does not appear in folder

Tags: php, file, move

I have a couple of scripts that worked fine on another server.

Now that I have moved everything on to a new server, the file does not appear in the destination folder. The strange thing is that `move_uploaded_file` returns `true`.

Also, I printed the post data and there is no error.

Can you guess what's possibly going on. The files I am trying to upload as a test are very small ( 10 kb).

Comment: could you please share some code with us?

Comment: Post some code. Also, triple check your permissions on the destination folder.

Comment: if it returns true, then the move succeeded - most likely you're overwriting some other file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The move likely succeeded, check the following:

- You don't have access to view the file.
  Use `chmod("/path/to/file.ext", 0755);` to add view rights for the ftp user.
- You moved the file to an location that doesn't store the file. `/dev/null`
- You're looking in the wrong folder. Did you use a full path?
- The file is removed shortly after the move.

Comment: thanks I found out that I needed to somehow force refresh of my ftp client in order to see the files. Also probably they were still in the server que, I don't know. Anyway the files were moved correctly in the destination folder and I was able to see them. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Total Commander, used as an FTP client, truncated output to 10000 files in directory. When I connected via SSH using WinSCP I was able to see all ~14000 files in the directory.